# how i put the text in the middle of a tabular and a figure?

Tags: tables

I try to put the text in the middle of the tabular and the figure but when I transform the document in PDF the text doesn't stay in the middle. How I can solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{relatorioFisExpI}

\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}

Atrav\'{e}s da an\'{a}lise de $\frac{(T-T_0)}{T_0}$, podemos registar os dados numa tabela:

\begin{table}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{ccc}

\toprule

Erro relativo (\%) & Amplitude ($^{\circ}$) \\

\midrule

0,01\% & 2$^{\circ}$ \\

0,1\% & 7$^{\circ}$ \\

1 \% & 25$^{\circ}$ \\

8\% & 60$^{\circ}$ \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{table}

Tamb\'{e}m podemos observar o seguinte gr\'{a}fico que representa o erro relativo de $T^*_1$:

\begin{figure}[H]

\centering

\includegraphics[width=95mm]{erroT1*.png}

\caption{Representa\c{c}\~{a}o gr\'{a}fica da aproxima\c{c}\~{a}o da express\~{a}o do per\'{i}odo a $T_1^*$ e indica\c{c}\~{a}o do erro relativo para cada \^{a}ngulo.}

\label{fig:rotacao do pendulo}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Which text are you referring to?

Comment: @cfr the text that I wanna stay in the middle of the tabular and the figure is: Tamb\'{e}m podemos observar o seguinte gr\'{a}fico que representa o erro relativo de $T^*_1$:

Comment: Can this be reproduced with a standard class? If not, where can we find `relatorioFisExpI.cls`?

Comment: @cfr this is the link with the files of cls https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ujp9t4met3hh4z/AABdOFz1Ai9cSJKq46bxSV9na?dl=0

Comment: You mean [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XAu9D.png)? That's what I get with `article.cls` when I add `booktabs`, `float` and `graphicx` and substitute a standard image.

Comment: @cfr I wanna the tabular under "Através da análise......" and the graphic under "Também podemos observar...". The sequence that I pretend is "Atraves da analise..." (text)- tabular - "Também podemos observar..."(text) - graphic.

Comment: @cfr in my computer appears like this: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1okvcwau994nlg/Captura%20de%20ecr%C3%A3%202016-04-2%2C%20%C3%A0s%2003.18.14.png?dl=0] But I don't wanna in this sequence... this is my problem

Comment: `\begin{table}[H]` or don't use floats at all, of course.

Comment: @cfr It works! I'm a beginner! I will continue working! :)

Comment: You could also put the tabular, text and graphics into a single float (figure or table, it doesn't matter much).

Comment: @CarmenGonzález: You have a bunch of questions with acceptable answers, but you accepted non so far. This is not how TeX.SX works

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the `table` and `figure` environments to "float" (in the LaTeX sense of the word), add the `[h!]` positioning specifier.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,demo,portuguese]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx,babel}
\begin{document}

Atrav\'{e}s da an\'{a}lise de $(T-T_0)/T_0$, podemos registar os dados numa tabela:
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
Erro relativo (\%) & Amplitude ($^{\circ}$) \\
\midrule
0,01\% & 2$^{\circ}$ \\
0,1\%  & 7$^{\circ}$ \\
1 \%   & 25$^{\circ}$ \\
8\%    & 60$^{\circ}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Tamb\'{e}m podemos observar o seguinte gr\'{a}fico que representa o erro relativo de~$T^*_1$:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{erroT1.png}
\caption{Representa\c{c}\~{a}o gr\'{a}fica da aproxima\c{c}\~{a}o da express\~{a}o do per\'{i}odo a~$T_1^*$ e indica\c{c}\~{a}o do erro relativo para cada \^{a}ngulo.}
\label{fig:rotacao do pendulo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- As the exchange of comments with @egreg highlights, the `[h!]` placement strategy may fail if there's not enough space left at the bottom of a page to place the `figure`: In such a case, (i) the float will be placed at the top of the following page, and (ii) the remainder of the page will be filled with text from after the `float`. This will look very strange to the reader if the paragraph prior to the intended float ends with `Tamb\'{e}m podemos observar o seguinte gr\'{a}fico que representa o erro relativo de~$T^*_1$:`, and if this sentence is followed immediately by the float but, instead, by more text.

In a LaTeX-based document, the *best policy* is to make the text and the *placement* of the floats more or less independent of each other. For the case at hand (I apologize for writing this in English; my Portuguese isn't up to snuff!), the sentence might therefore be rephrased as `Figure~\ref{fig:rotacao do pendulo} demonstrates this relationship (of the relative error of $T^*_1$ [?]) graphically.`

Comment: `[h!]` will not inhibit the floating; it may, instead, block the float queue and push all floats at the end of the document or chapter.

Comment: @egreg - LaTeX replaces `[h!]` automatically with `[ht!]`. If LaTeX cannot fit a float at the top of the (next) page (despite the `!`, which overrides various default placement constraints), something is likely to be seriously non-standard about the size of the float, in which case its placement will likely be deferred to the very end of the document anyway -- with or without the `[h!]` placement specifier. I should maybe have noted in the posting that an advantage of `[h!]` (or `[ht!]`, if you prefer) over `[H]` of the `float` package) is that no ugly gaps at the bottom of pages can occur.

Comment: So specify `[!htp]` (the addition of `t` is a safety measure, but it's better to be explicit). Of course, in case the float goes top of the next page, the colon in `erro relativo de~$T^*_1$:` will look *very* funny. The solution is to make the text independent of the float's placement and then let the figure/table to float.

Comment: @egreg - I fully agree with you that it's best to make the text independent of the placement of the floats -- and, in general, to let LaTeX place the floats wherever LaTeX feels it's best to do so. The OP's question, though, was how to deviate from what you and I consider to be the optimal approach. I didn't think this was the right place to try dissuading him/her from pursuing this alternate path...